# How to create table in PostgreSQL using R?

Tags: r, postgresql, dbi

I'd like to create table in PostgrSQL using R `DBI` package.
Here is s small example.

```
dbExecute(con, "create table data1 (var1 int not null, var2 date not null, var3 int)")
```

where `con` is connection object.

But I got an error `Failed to fetch row` and something else that I cannot read due to UTF-8 encoding problem.

Also I tried `dbSendQuery` and `dbGetquery`. The same result.

How can write a code to complete this task?
A one restiction applied. I know that there is a `dbCreateTable`command which creates table in PosgreSQL. But it uses R notation, but I want apply exact SQL notation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide in your question the error message you get ?

Comment: @Waldi The error message had been incorporated into my question.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on my instance of postgres. Is it possible that the connection "user" does not have permissions to create a (non-temporary) table? Perhaps `create temporary table data1 (...)` will work? (Granted, that's meant solely for troubleshooting, not as a permanent solution, this the table will vanish as soon as you disconnect or the connection is otherwise interrupted.)

Answer (score 0):

I got the way out.
All I need is to read the following code:

```
RPostgres:: dbSendQuery(con, "create table ...")
```